# Application cant be installed with error message "Package is Corrupted"

Tags: android

My application is running smoothly on the devices when run from the android studio. But when I send the app_debug.apk file from the mail, download and try to install it, the application is not installed giving message "Package corrupted".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid this follow these steps to make a build in android studio

Android Studio - Go to Build - click on build apk 
then go to your project click on build folder -output-find your apk there it wont give any error like package corrupt.